# Count number of users that purchased in certain stores at certain dates

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have two tables:

- "`purchases`" table has 3 columns: "`user_id`", "`store_id`", "`purchase_date`"
  (so I can know that `client_id=XXX` made a purchase in `store_id=YYY` on
  `date=YYYY-MM-DD`).
- "`stores`" table has "`store_id`", "`latitude`", "`longitude`", "`date`" (so at that `date=YYYY-MM-DD`, the `store_id=YYY` was located in `latitude=AAA` and `longitude=BBB`).

I would like to count the number of clients that purchased in stores located at certain geographical regions at some date, and another region in another date.

For example, I want to count the number of users that purchased in stores in USA in May 2022 and also purchased in stores in Japan during June 2022.

I tried this:

```
SELECT count(distinct user)
FROM (
"purchases" WHERE store_id IN ( 
    SELECT store_id FROM "stores" WHERE ( latitude BETWEEN 23 AND 50 ) AND ( longitude BETWEEN -127 AND -66 ) AND ( date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-31' 
) 
AND store_id IN ( 
    SELECT store_id FROM "stores" WHERE ( latitude BETWEEN 30 AND 45 ) AND ( longitude BETWEEN 130 AND 150 ) AND ( date BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30' 
)
)
```

But does not work, I don't know how to do it...

Comment: *Two* tables? Don't you have a user table? The column `user_id` suggests that.

Comment: And please never say it "does not work", without telling us in what regard it doesn't work. Are you getting an error message? Which? Or too many rows? Too few? Wrong ones? Wrong in which regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count
FROM (
  SELECT p.user_id
  FROM purchases p INNER JOIN stores s
  ON s.store_id = p.store_id
  GROUP BY p.user_id
  HAVING SUM(s.latitude BETWEEN 23 AND 50 AND s.longitude BETWEEN -127 AND -66 AND p.purchase_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-31') > 0
     AND SUM(s.latitude BETWEEN 30 AND 45 AND s.longitude BETWEEN 130 AND 150 AND p.purchase_date BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND '2022-06-30') > 0
) t;
```

Comment: Aggregation is a good approach here. You should explain, though, why you can add up boolean expressions in MySQL. And be aware that the `BETWEEN` clause is faulty, and MySQL won't even report a syntax error due to their sloppy conversion rules.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what do you mean by *the BETWEEN clause is faulty*?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It has become so rare now that I use `BETWEEN` that I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step with the help of CTEs (`WITH` clauses):

```
with us_stores as
(
  SELECT *
  FROM stores
  WHERE latitude BETWEEN 23 AND 50 
  AND longitude BETWEEN -127 AND -66 
)
, jp_stores as
(
  SELECT *
  FROM stores
  WHERE latitude BETWEEN 30 AND 45
  AND longitude BETWEEN 130 AND 150
)
, us_purchasers as
(
  select distinct user_id
  from purchases
  where store_id in (select store_id from us_stores)
  and date >= date '2022-05-01'
  and date < date '2022-06-01'
)
, jp_purchasers as
(
  select distinct user_id
  from purchases
  where store_id in (select store_id from jp_stores)
  and date >= date '2022-06-01'
  and date < date '2022-07-01'
)
select count(*)
from us_purchasers
join jp_purchasers using (user_id);
```